# Running bash script with php under lower priority or limit CPU

Tags: php, bash, cpu-usage

I have a bash script which runs a set of php scripts. When it runs it takes an hour and pegs the CPU at 95-99%. This causes our lamp stack (mainly the apache process) problems and our website on the same server starts spitting out timeout or 500 errors.

How can I either:

- Run the bash script and all associated tasks (php scripts which also call the PostgreSQL db) at a low priority so apache, php and db tasks for the web server are always prioritized, OR
- Limit the CPU usage for the script and associated tasks to, e.g. 25% CPU

I'm not sure which is the better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to `nice`, looking at limiting CPU time, using `ulimit -t` (assuming you are on a *nix platform)

Comment: Didn't know about that one!

Comment: Thanks. So does nice also prioritize other processes kicked off by the bash script?

Comment: Normally, all processes inherit nice value of their parent process when they are spawned.

Answer (score 2):

Run your commands through `nice`.

> **nice** runs utility at an altered scheduling priority.  If an increment
>   is
>        given, it is used; otherwise an increment of 10 is assumed.  The super-
>        user can run utilities with priorities higher than normal by using a neg-
>        ative increment.  The priority can be adjusted over a range of -20 (the
>        highest) to 20 (the lowest).
>
> ```
>  Available options:
>
>  -n increment
>          A positive or negative decimal integer used to modify the system
>          scheduling priority of utility.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, `nice` is what you want. Limiting to 25% of the CPU is boneheaded. This will needlessly extend the amount of time that system performance is reduced.

Say you have four cars and need to do a few errands. Which makes more sense, using one car to do the errands or using all unused car to do the errands? The former leaves 4 cars for important tasks. The latter leaves only 3. And in most realistic cases, the former will also get the low-priority job done sooner.